# Extending lists using list comprehension in python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

So let's say I have list 
    **items** = ['abc', 'def', 'tre'].

Now I want to insert a flag before each of list items.

E.g the new list **items2** should be ['-g', 'abc', '-g', 'def', '-g', 'tre'].

I could read the list and append each one after appended the flag but I want to start doing it the python way.

What I came up with is:

```
items2.extend(['-g', i] for i in items )
```

What this gives me a list with smaller lists:

```
items2 = [['-g', 'abc'], ['-g', 'def'], ['-g', 'tre']]
```

I understand that this is because it would be equivalent to saying

```
items2.extend([ ... ] , [ ... ], [ ... ])
```

Any ideas about this? Thanks

Comment: To flatten your list, just use `itertools.chain(*items2)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[j for i in items for j in '-g', i]
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> items = ['abc', 'def', 'tre']
>>> zip(['-g', '-g', '-g'], items)
[('-g', 'abc'), ('-g', 'def'), ('-g', 'tre')]
```

After that, you can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to flatten the list:

```
>>> list(itertools.chain(*zip(['-g', '-g', '-g'], items)))
['-g', 'abc', '-g', 'def', '-g', 'tre']
```

Note that due to function call overhead, this is quite slow, compared to a simple list comprehension:

```
In [17]: %timeit [j for i in items for j in '-g', i]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 923 ns per loop

In [18]: %timeit list(itertools.chain(*zip(['-g', '-g', '-g'], items)))
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.67 µs per loop
```

So for performance and clarity, I suggest you use [Robᵩ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25537130/89391).

Comment: I don't think this is the required output

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to other excellent `zip` based answers, you might use [`itertools.repeat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) instead of "counting" items:

```
>>> items = ['abc', 'def', 'tre']
>>> list(itertools.chain(*zip(itertools.repeat('-g'), items)))
#                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#                             repeat as much as needed
['-g', 'abc', '-g', 'def', '-g', 'tre']
```

And if you don't like *zip*, an alternative:

```
>>> list(itertools.chain(*[('-g', i) for i in items]))
['-g', 'abc', '-g', 'def', '-g', 'tre']
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple way is to loop through your list and insert after every element.

```
for i in range(len(items)):
   items.insert((i*2)+1,'-g')
```

As you insert your length up to the insertion point doubles, so you need to put your next element at (i*2)+1

Comment: Not sexy. Not very pythonic. But fast probably. I don't have the time to run a benchmark, but I'll bet this is the most _efficient_ solution.